# How to take name and last name with match function?

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, ecmascript-6

You can add comment in my project and you can reply my comment. I want to take the name and surname after "@". How can I do that?

My find username function

```
const findUsername = message => {
var attachments = message.match(/@[^\s]+/g);
console.log(attachments);
return attachments !== null
  ? attachments.map(item => item).join('')
  : null;  };
```

This function just take the name, example: "@John Dao", function take the John. Anybody help me ?

Comment Example:

[Comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8XIP.png)

Reply Example:

[Reply Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftp9r.png)

Message argument example : "@Berkay Ergün skajjkdalskjdadsa"

Comment: `message.match(/@(\S+)\s+(\S+)/);`?

Comment: use `message.split('@')`

Comment: Is the surname guaranteed? Is there ever a middle initial? What kind of content exists after the name?

Comment: Please provide a sample string and point out what you wish to extract from it.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew
it two takes name and last name, Example: @John Dao@JohnDao

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I edited the post. Please check. It may be 2 names but it's not a big deal

Comment: @berkayer ... your updated example of `'@Berkay Ergün skajjkdalskjdadsa'` does not allow any middle name(s). Are there more reliable rules/patterns to tell the name from the rest apart? Otherwise go with the first solution provided by _Wiktor Stribiżew_.

Comment: @PeterSeliger No, this field comes from backend. https://prnt.sc/Hoew9UF39KhY

Comment: @berkayer ... an applied version of _Wiktors_ suggested approach then might be similar to this ... `const [ match, name, lastname ] = '@Berkay Ergün skajjkdalskjdadsa'.match(/@(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) ?? [];`

Comment: So if `@JohnDao` exists then it's guaranteed to be capitalized like that? English letters only?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, there is also turkish word.

Comment: So how do you expect to identify the firstname/lastname of `@Berkay Ergün skajjkdalskjdadsa` versus `@BerkayErgün MonkeyZeus made a comment`?

Comment: Regex is just a character matcher, not a language interpreter.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```js
const splitName = (name = '') => {
  const res = name.substring(1)
  const [firstName, ...lastName] = res.split(' ').filter(Boolean);
  return {
    name: firstName,
    surname: lastName.join(' ')
  }
}

console.log(splitName('@Jon  Doe'));
```

Comment: does not work for the OP's example of e.g. `console.log(splitName('@Berkay Ergün skajjkdalskjdadsa'));`